# Code Contracts - Visual Studio Team Service Scripted Build Server Unit Tests Fail

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-contracts, azure-devops

I recently added Code Contracts to my solution. After some modifications our build runs without any problems but our unit tests fail because of Code Contracts.

**Environment:**

- Source control and build server are hosted on [Visual Studio Team Service](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/build-your-app-vs) (VSTS) Scripted Build (*formerly VSO*)
- VS 2013 Premium Code (*now VS 2015 Enterprise*) contracts enabled on configurations `Debug` and `Release`
- Code contract turned off with `DoNotBuild` flag set for custom configurations `BuildServer`
- [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/build-your-app-vs) build definition:

  1. Has step Visual Studio
  2. has flags set `/p:CodeContractsEnableRuntimeChecking=false;CodeContractsReferenceAssembly=false`

**Example error text from build server:**

> Test method
>   Web.Tests.AccountControllerTests.CreateAccount_Pass_NoPasswordSend_Test
>   threw exception:  System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractException: An
>   assembly (probably "Cms.Web") must be rewritten using the code
>   contracts binary rewriter (CCRewrite) because it is calling
>   Contract.Requires and the CONTRACTS_FULL symbol is
>   defined.  Remove any explicit definitions of the CONTRACTS_FULL symbol
>   from your project and rebuild.

I have examined the diagnostic output from the build server and there is no symbol `CONTRACTS_FULL` that can be found anywhere.

I do not want to enable code contracts on the build server mostly because I had tried that before with no success and due to time constraints I gave up (*after more searching I came to the conclusion that this is not possible as Microsoft does not allow for custom extensions to be installed on the build server*). I simply want to ignore code contracts on the build server but the Unit Test execution does not seem to do this.

Any one have any ideas on where I need to look to ensure code contracts are ignored by the unit tests? Seems like this should be possible right? Maybe there is another flag I could set in the build definition that will be picked up by the unit tests?

---

**Edit**

Please note the build server is **HOSTED** in the cloud as a Microsoft service as a part of Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online). This means it is not our build server, we have no control over what is installed on the build server. Even so we want to use Code Contracts. The accepted answer below is a way to allow for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, please read the Code Contracts manual. It tells you everything you need to know. You don't need any `ConditionalAttribute` defined on your methods. You can use `Contract.Requires<TException>(bool condition)` if you know what the requirements for doing so are.

As @Mixxiphoid said in their answer, because they were using the generic form of Requires, Code Contracts is required to be installed on the build server *and* **Peform Runtime Contract Checking** needs to be enabled for the Release configuration *in addition to* the Debug configuration.

If you are using Code Contracts, then you will *always* need Code Contracts installed on the build servers that build Debug releases. The same goes for your team: all developers who need to compile the code will be required to have Code Contracts installed for Debug builds.

It's all in **Section 5: Usage Guidelines** in the Code Contracts manual. There's a helpful diagram on **page 20** that gives a great summary of the various usage scenarios and their requirements.

---

### About `Contract.Requires<TException>(bool condition)`

First off, the developer that wrote this method for Code Contracts ***did not*** forget to apply the `ConditionalAttribute` to the method, as the accepted answer states. Far from it. The very fact that this method is not decorated with that attribute is ***by design***.

If you read **Section 5: Usage Guidelines**, you see that if you use this form of the `Requires` method, then you are required to use the binary rewriter—`ccrewrite`—when building your assembly. This implies that any machine which will build your assembly must have `ccrewrite` available.

So, what about build servers that you may not control? I'm glad you asked.

---

### TFS Hosted Build Servers

With respect to TFS hosted build servers: It's true that you cannot simply install Code Contracts on the build servers. So what are your options?

1. You could limit yourself to using only the "legacy" form of code contracts, *if-then-throw* blocks followed by `Contract.EndContractBlock()` or limit yourself to only using `Contract.Requires(bool condition)` (the non-generic form), or a mixture of the two.

   - In either case, you'll probably want to have a separate Debug build configuration for the TFS-hosted build server. This build configuration would have **Perform Runtime Contract Checking** disabled for that build configuration.
2. You could do a little "bing-ing" or "googling" and come up with [this](http://blog.mycupof.net/2013/03/30/team-foundation-service-make-codecontracts-work-on-a-hosted-build-agent/) search result, which describes how to enable building your solution with Code Contracts on TFS Online.

The blog post linked to above has instructions for modifying a TFS Hosted Build Controller hosted build.

**UPDATE: THERE WILL SOON BE A NUGET VERSION OF CODE CONTRACTS**
For those of you using hosted build services, such as Visual Studio Online, AppVeyor, etc., the new community-driven Code Contracts GitHub repo recently announced **v1.10.xxxxx.RC1**. In the release notes, they mention a [NuGet version of code contracts](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues/13). Enjoy.

Comment: The down vote was unjustified. Just because you use a hosted build server doesn't excuse the fact that the time was not taken to read and understand the code contracts manual. Then you would know what usage scenarios would be appropriate.

Comment: I do not believe my initial down vote was unjust, what you had previously added nothing to the thread (discussion). It mas merely 'you should have looked at the documentation, here is the chapter', and IMO almost as bad as just supplying a link. It would have been a good comment but not an answer. Your revision here is good and addresses the question, it also includes actual steps you can take should you encounter the same problem. I rescind my down vote and will also up vote. Thanks for your time/effort.

Comment: @Igor, I really appreciate that. I love being a help to the community. I spent the majority of all day Saturday answering Code Contracs questions. Most of the questions I answered were all readily found in the manual, particularly, Section 5: Usage Guidelines. In my opinion, if one doesn't read anything else in that manual, then one should at least read that section and ensure they understand it--it'll save you a world of headaches. :)  Thanks again!

Comment: I downvoted because it starts down an offensive path by starting the answer with "please, please". It would be more effective to start with something softer, such as "It would be very helpful to read...".

Answer (score 4):

After double checking this build configuration also has the same errors in the unit test as on the build server. After some digging I came up with the answer.

The answer lies in `Contract.Requires`. The generic version of method `Contract.Requires<T>` does not apply the attribute `[Conditional("CONTRACTS_FULL")]` where as the non-generic method `Contract.Requires` does. This means that `Contract.Requires<T>` is always evaluated and there is nothing you can do about it. See [Cutting Edge - Code Contracts Settings in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148151.aspx) for more detail.

After I reverted all of my code to make use of `Contract.Requires` instead of `Contract.Requires<T>` all my unit tests were able to execute again. You can still make use of `ContractClassFor` and `ContractClass` attributes and make use of the generic `Contract.Requires<T>` implementation within the contract class without any problem, this because the contract class will not get built without `CONTRACTS_FULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Got the exact same problem this morning. The solution was to enable runtime contract checking on release mode instead of only debug mode.

Beside that, CodeContracts had to be installed on the build server as well.